# How do i resize an SVG?

Tags: css, svg, highcharts

for my project i am using Highcharts, The style is defined by some Javascript and i was wondering if it is somehow possible to resize the SVG or the parents container?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="beteiligungs_chart">
<div class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 1706px; height: 400px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; cursor: auto;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1706" height="400">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
                <rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="9999" height="400" stroke-width="0.000001"></rect>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="highcharts-2">
                <rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="1706" height="400"></rect>
            </clipPath>
            <radialGradient cx="853" cy="160" r="140" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="highcharts-3">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(54,93,150)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(54,93,150)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient cx="853" cy="160" r="140" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="highcharts-4">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(8,71,153)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(8,71,153)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient cx="853" cy="160" r="140" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="highcharts-5">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(80,139,28)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(80,139,28)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient cx="853" cy="160" r="140" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="highcharts-6">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(25,125,31)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(25,125,31)" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" x="0" y="0" width="1706" height="400" stroke-width="0.000001" fill-opacity="0"></rect>
        <g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3"></g>
        <g class="highcharts-shadow" zIndex="4">
            <path fill="none" d="M 852.9796326796305 100.00000207413872 A 100 100 0 1 1 852.9797326796285 299.9999979461786 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 1 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 852.9796326796305 100.00000207413872 A 100 100 0 1 1 852.9797326796285 299.9999979461786 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 1 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 852.9796326796305 100.00000207413872 A 100 100 0 1 1 852.9797326796285 299.9999979461786 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 1 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-shadow" zIndex="4">
            <path fill="none" d="M 852.9796326796305 299.9999979258613 A 100 100 0 0 1 753.0499037961571 203.1588397937432 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 852.9796326796305 299.9999979258613 A 100 100 0 0 1 753.0499037961571 203.1588397937432 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 852.9796326796305 299.9999979258613 A 100 100 0 0 1 753.0499037961571 203.1588397937432 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-shadow" zIndex="4">
            <path fill="none" d="M 753.0499006373673 203.15873984364538 A 100 100 0 0 1 846.7650487338601 100.19456235901343 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 753.0499006373673 203.15873984364538 A 100 100 0 0 1 846.7650487338601 100.19456235901343 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 753.0499006373673 203.15873984364538 A 100 100 0 0 1 846.7650487338601 100.19456235901343 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-shadow" zIndex="4">
            <path fill="none" d="M 846.7651485393009 100.19455612411205 A 100 100 0 0 1 852.9610019625195 100.00000760423492 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 846.7651485393009 100.19455612411205 A 100 100 0 0 1 852.9610019625195 100.00000760423492 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
            <path fill="none" d="M 846.7651485393009 100.19455612411205 A 100 100 0 0 1 852.9610019625195 100.00000760423492 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-point" zIndex="5">
            <path fill="url(http://gw.lo/print/5132#highcharts-3)" d="M 852.9796326796305 100.00000207413872 A 100 100 0 1 1 852.9797326796285 299.9999979461786 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 1 0 853 200 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-point" zIndex="5">
            <path fill="url(http://gw.lo/print/5132#highcharts-4)" d="M 852.9796326796305 299.9999979258613 A 100 100 0 0 1 753.0499037961571 203.1588397937432 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-point" zIndex="5">
            <path fill="url(http://gw.lo/print/5132#highcharts-5)" d="M 753.0499006373673 203.15873984364538 A 100 100 0 0 1 846.7650487338601 100.19456235901343 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-point" zIndex="5">
            <path fill="url(http://gw.lo/print/5132#highcharts-6)" d="M 846.7651485393009 100.19455612411205 A 100 100 0 0 1 852.9610019625195 100.00000760423492 L 853 200 A 0 0 0 0 0 853 200 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7">
            <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="7" height="7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#909090" visibility="hidden"></rect>
            <g zIndex="1" clip-path="url(http://gw.lo/print/5132#highcharts-1)">
                <g></g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-tooltip" zIndex="8" style="padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" visibility="hidden">
            <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0.85" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)"></rect>
            <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0.85" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)"></rect>
            <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.85" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)"></rect>
            <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.85"></rect>
            <text x="5" y="18" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" zIndex="1"></text>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-tracker" zIndex="9"></g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I tried to style every element but it did not work. For example: I tried to set the height and width of the container #beteiligungs-chart to 500px - the inspector shows a box but the svg won't move.

Is there something i missed?

It would be awesome if someone could take a look at my problem :)
thanks!

Morten

Comment: add a viewBox to the svg, ex viewBox="0 0 800 600"

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to call `chart.setSize(new_width, new_height);` ? See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize).